# SharePoint Save as Template not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, large-lists

So I have a list, where I want to be able to copy an item between different lists. My plan was to use sharepoint2013 and save the list as a template, and then use that list as a template for my others. However, whenever I hit "Save as Template" my computer just freezes up for a few seconds and then does nothing!

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

At first it pulled up an instance of internet explorer telling me I didn't have the rights access the page, even though I ended up giving EVERYONE full access just to try and get past that screen. then after I disabled, and re-enabled the internet explorer, the button stopped doing anything at all but freeze everything up for a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Save as Template doesn't just require permissions in the site, it also requires permissions in the template galleries at the site collection level.  Generally this is restricted to site collection admins.  Can you validate that you have contribute permissions to the list template gallery?

Comment: I'm not sure. what is a site collection admin?

Comment: Here is a good article describing the Site Collector Administrator role:  https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/what-is-a-sharepoint-site-collection-administrator/

Comment: I am the owner. I also made a few other developers who are working with me owners as well. But It looks like I am the only site collector admin